# Install opencv for python3 on ubuntu 14 without compiling from source

Tags: linux, python-3.x, opencv, install.packages

Is it possible to install opencv for python3 on ubuntu 14 without compiling from source?

Update:
Also using `pip3 search` I can see package `opencv-python`, but for some reason I can't install it.

```
pip3 search opencv | grep opencv
pyElphel                  - Use Elphel camera from python with opencv2
cv2-wrapper               - Wrapper for python opencv 2.4.12 32bit
opencv_cffi               - A random subset of OpenCV's functionality, wrapped via CFFI
opencv-python-armv7l      - opencv-python on armv7l.
airtest                   - Automation test library for android based on opencv
opencv-contrib-python     - Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
helper_functions          - A simple module of simple function, for opencv and python3
atx                       - Automation test library for android based on opencv
aircv                     - Find object position based on python-opencv2.
ctypes-opencv             - ctypes-opencv - A Python wrapper for OpenCV using ctypes
cv2wrap                   - Wrapper for python opencv 2.4.12 32bit
opencv_engine             - OpenCV imaging engine for thumbor.
opencv-utils              - OpenCV Utilities
opencv-python-aarch64     - Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
simple-opencv-ocr         - A simple OCR with OpenCV
pyopencv                  - PyOpenCV - A Python wrapper for OpenCV 2.x using Boost.Python and NumPy
opencv-cython             - An alternative OpenCV wrapper
opencv_helpers            - Helper functions for opencv
opencvutils               - Simple OpenCV 3.x image processing functions
opencv-python             - Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
```

`pip3 install opencv-python`
`tail /home/user/.pip/pip.log`

```
No distributions at all found for opencv-python
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for opencv-python
```

via `apt-cache search`, looks like `python-opencv` is for python2.

```
apt-cache search opencv | grep opencv
libopencv-calib3d-dev - development files for libopencv-calib3d
libopencv-calib3d2.4 - computer vision Camera Calibration library
libopencv-contrib-dev - development files for libopencv-contrib
libopencv-contrib2.4 - computer vision contrib library
libopencv-core-dev - development files for libopencv-core
libopencv-core2.4 - computer vision core library
libopencv-dev - development files for opencv
libopencv-features2d-dev - development files for libopencv-features2d
libopencv-features2d2.4 - computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
libopencv-flann-dev - development files for libopencv-flann
libopencv-flann2.4 - computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
libopencv-gpu-dev - development files for libopencv-gpu2.4
libopencv-gpu2.4 - computer vision GPU library
libopencv-highgui-dev - development files for libopencv-highgui
libopencv-highgui2.4 - computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
libopencv-imgproc-dev - development files for libopencv-imgproc
libopencv-imgproc2.4 - computer vision Image Processing library
libopencv-legacy-dev - development files for libopencv-legacy
libopencv-legacy2.4 - computer vision legacy library
libopencv-ml-dev - development files for libopencv-ml
libopencv-ml2.4 - computer vision Machine Learning library
libopencv-objdetect-dev - development files for libopencv-objdetect
libopencv-objdetect2.4 - computer vision Object Detection library
libopencv-ocl-dev - development files for libopencv-ocl2.4
libopencv-ocl2.4 - computer vision OpenCL support library
libopencv-photo-dev - development files for libopencv-photo2.4
libopencv-photo2.4 - computer vision computational photography library
libopencv-stitching-dev - development files for libopencv-stitching2.4
libopencv-stitching2.4 - computer vision image stitching library
libopencv-superres-dev - development files for libopencv-superres2.4
libopencv-superres2.4 - computer vision Super Resolution library
libopencv-ts-dev - development files for libopencv-ts2.4
libopencv-ts2.4 - computer vision ts library
libopencv-video-dev - development files for libopencv-video
libopencv-video2.4 - computer vision Video analysis library
libopencv-videostab-dev - development files for libopencv-videostab2.4
libopencv-videostab2.4 - computer vision video stabilization library
libopencv2.4-java - Java bindings for the computer vision library
libopencv2.4-jni - Java jni library for the computer vision library
opencv-data - development data for opencv
opencv-doc - OpenCV documentation and examples
python-opencv - Python bindings for the computer vision library
```

Comment: get the pre-compiled wheel from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python, then `pip install opencv-xxx.whl`.

Comment: Note that the above `opencv-python` package will only work on x86/x86_64, not ARM.

Comment: Try with `apt-get install libopencv-dev`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Looks like there no suitable .whl for Ubuntu 14 default python `Python 3.4.3`.